# How to set property using "tasklet ref" tag

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have a tasklet ValidarSituacaoTasklet that has an property situacao. This tasklet is used in 2 steps in distinct values for situacao. I declared steps as like:
    
        
    
and the bean:

```
<bean id="validarSituacaoTasklet" class="my.package.tasklet.ValidarSituacaoTasklet" scope="step">
</bean>
```

I have to pass 'situacao' to tasklet . 
I tried:

```
<step id="validaSituacaoStep">
    <tasklet ref="validarSituacaoTasklet ">
        <property name="situacao" value="EM_FECHAMENTO"/>
    </tasklet>
</step>
```

but it does not seem to be the right way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't this what you want:

```
<step id="validaSituacaoStep">
    <tasklet ref="validarSituacaoTasklet "/>
</step>

<bean id="validarSituacaoTasklet" class="my.package.tasklet.ValidarSituacaoTasklet" scope="step">
    <property name="situacao" value="EM_FECHAMENTO"/>
</bean>
```

**UPDATE**

Based on the comment left, this should work:

```
<step id="validaSituacaoStep">
    <tasklet>
        <bean class="my.package.tasklet.ValidarSituacaoTasklet" scope="step">
            <property name="situacao" value="EM_FECHAMENTO"/>
        </bean>
    <tasklet>
</step>
```

Comment: It works, but in this way I have to declare onde bean for each value for 'situacao'. I declared the beans in a separated beans.XML file. I would like to define situacao when I use the bean, in step declaration.

Comment: I just updated my comment, however, just to confirm...you are using Spring Batch's configuration and not JSR-352, correct?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following ?

```
<bean id="validarSituacaoTasklet" class="my.package.tasklet.ValidarSituacaoTasklet" scope="step">
       <property name="situacao" ref="daoBean"/>
</bean>
```

The DAO should be referenced at your bean's definition

Comment: It should work, but I'd like  to define "situacao" when I use the tasklet on step, since I have to many values to 'situacao' and I don't want to declare one bean for each situation. I thought there would be a way to declare property when I refer it using <tasklet ref> but if there is not a better way I will declare one bean for each situation.